# Making an HTTP POST request in C# with UTF32?

Tags: c#, http, post

I want to make a HTTP POST request in C# with UTF32. I can find plenty of resources on this with UTF8, but none of them appear to work properly - at least not in my scenario where UTF32 is needed.

Can you help me?

**Edit 1**
The code is located here:

```
    public static void SubmitMap(string mapPath)
    {

        var request = WebRequest.Create(Domain + "/MapCloud/SubmitMap");
        request.Method = "POST";

        var postData = "facebookID=" + IngamableCommunicator.FacebookProfileID + "&name=Sample&content=" + /*HttpUtility.UrlEncode(File.ReadAllText(mapPath)*/ "lala";
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        response.GetResponseStream();

        //dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        //string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        //reader.Close();

        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

    }
```

The code returns an error 500. Of course, this could be an issue with the server. But the server is configured to output a stacktrace as a string in case of an error.

**Edit 2**
I tried changing the content type to "text/plain" which it basically is. Still no luck.

**Edit 3**
The server is running ASP .NET MVC 3 on the .NET Framework 4.0, and the controller for the area that is contacted looks like this:

```
public class MapCloudController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitMap(string name, string content, int facebookID)
    {

        try
        {

            var container = new ModelContainer();

            Gamer gamer = container.GamerSet.FirstOrDefault(g => g.FacebookID == facebookID);

            var map = new ScaveniusMap();
            map.Content = content;
            map.Name = name;
            map.SubmissionTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            map.Owner = gamer;

            container.AddToScaveniusMapSet(map);
            Debug.Assert(gamer != null, "gamer != null");
            gamer.Maps.Add(map);

            container.SaveChanges();
            container.Dispose();

            ViewBag.Error = "No error";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = facebookID + ": " + ex;
        }

        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.Status = "success";
        Response.SubStatusCode = 0;

        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you add code to illustrate what you've tried? It's probably worth mentioning the server software in use at "the other end" of your post.

Comment: Why UTF-32, anyway? Also, the payload you send doesn't look like "application/x-www-form-urlencode" to me...

Comment: Check you have the correct content type.

Comment: The mimetype is now correct. Still no luck.

Comment: The payload coming with status 500 may help. And, again, why UTF-32? Maybe the server doesn't support that and that's why it's failing?

Comment: I added the server-side code as well.

Comment: what is the payload of the 500 response? And again, why do you want to send UTF-32????

Comment: I use UTF32 because the text file contains characters that require it. I use all characters in UTF32 for this.

Comment: Mathias, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 can *all* represent all Unicode characters.

Comment: Julian, not according to this, and my own research: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode. It didn't work when I used UTF8 and UTF16. Special characters (invisible ones too) weren't transfered, and were instead loaded as question marks.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page you cite: "UTF-8 uses one to four bytes per code point and, being compact for Latin scripts and ASCII-compatible, provides the de facto standard encoding for interchange of Unicode text. It is also used by most recent Linux distributions as a direct replacement for legacy encodings in general text handling."

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"at least not in my scenario where UTF32 is needed"

UTF-32 isn't needed. You can express any Unicode code point using UTF-8.

The server you are talking to likely doesn't support UTF-32, and that's the whole problem.

Also, if you use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", you may even have the option to select the character encoding. Instead, you'll have to percent-encode those characters that are not ASCII (see HTML4 spec which defines this media type).

Comment: With all respect, I did a full multiplayer implementation of my game. With UTF8, some characters wouldn't display correctly, and would display as "?". There's a reason UTF32 takes up 4 bytes per character, and UTF8 takes up 1. It's no coincidence to WASTE space.

Comment: Mathias: UTF-8 takes up 1 byte only for code points 0..127. It takes multiple bytes for all others. Check http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-3.

If UTF8 didn't work for you then this was caused by something else; maybe an incorrect declaration.

Comment: Exactly, and I need ALL unicode characters, as I described ;)

Comment: Mathias, this is getting frustrating. Please go reading about UTF-8 and the come back. You *really* are wrong.

As an exercise, give me a Unicode code point, and I'll tell you the UTF8 representation.

Comment: You said so yourself. You said "It takes multiple bytes for all others". I have all others in one file - the data I am sending! I am sending the full capacity of UTF32 to the server!

Comment: Mathias: ok, I give up. Question: if you don't want help, why are you asking over here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5831/discussion-between-mathias-lykkegaard-lorenzen-and-julian-reschke)

Answer (score 1):

With you HttpWebRequest object, do as follows:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://posturl") as HttpWebRequest;
var encodedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("your string of data");
using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
   stream.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);
```