# Error 500 for UTF32, not for UTF8 in MVC

Tags: c#

In my MVC web application, I am calling a POST to a specific controller through a WebClient. I need this call to be in UTF32. However, whenever I do this with UTF32 it doesn't work. It returns an error 500. When I switch to UTF8, it works just fine.

Here's my UTF32 code:

```
var name = SettingsManager.GetScopeAttribute("[Map.Options]", "Name");

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  //client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
  client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", 
                     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-32");
  client.UploadData(url, Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("facebookID=" 
    + IngamableCommunicator.FacebookProfileID 
    + "&name=" 
    + name 
    + "&content=" 
    + File.ReadAllText(mapPath)));
}
```

The server reports this issue:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'facebookID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SubmitMap(Int32, System.String, System.String)' in 'FlamefusionEntertainment.Areas.Scavenius.Controllers.MapCloudController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

The problem I am having with UTF8 is that when the data actually goes through, since I have characters (invisible spaces etc) that are special, it goes wrong when saved in the Microsoft SQL database through Entity Framework.

The data I retrieve is somehow malformed. Some newlines are missing, some whitespaces aren't there, and so on.

Comment: And what is the exception causing the 500 error? What are the error details?

Comment: That's the thing. It doesn't even get to execute the controller. Not even on the first breakpoint in the first line of the controller.

Comment: And what does the event log say?

Comment: Of course the server, that's where the 500 error happened, after all.

Comment: I added the error to the message.

Comment: The error indicates that you are not passing in a _required_ `facebookID` to your `SubmitMap` action of the `MapCloud` controller.

Comment: You probably think it's off topic, but given encodings shouldn't affect the semantics of an action, why does your submission *have* to be in `UTF32`?

Comment: Ah, I see this is part of an [ongoing discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489129/making-an-http-post-request-in-c-sharp-with-utf32) where you don't believe people when they tell you that UTF8 supports the full unicode character set, so you're chasing down a dead-end, where even if/when you get UTF32 to work, you probably still won't have solved your original issue.

Comment: Oded, look at the code. It's there. The thing is, when I change to UTF8, it works just fine. Damien - explain to me why changing it to UTF8 then works correctly, and UTF32 doesn't?

Comment: Damien, I need all characters from 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF, which is UTF32's capacity. Do you still claim I can use UTF8?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen - As people have *repeatedly* tried to explain to you, UTF8 and UTF32 are different *encodings* of Unicode. *Both* of them support the full range of unicode characters. If you're using UTF8, and things *aren't* working as you expect, then switching to UTF32 isn't going to fix the issue.

Comment: Okay. I updated the question to describe the problem I am having in more detail.

Comment: Could it be because I am using UrlEncode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it's because MVC apparently doesn't support UTF32 requests. As Damien pointed out, there's no difference between UTF32 and UTF8 in terms of content. Therefore, it all worked when I switched to UTF8.

I figured out that it was because I was using the HttpUtility class' UrlEncode function to encode form data variables. Instead, I should have used the UrlEncodeUnicode function.